# Job offer accepted, having another interview where I really want to work. How to communicate this in the inverview?

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer, ethics

**The Situation**

I have finished by study and applied to several jobs and have already had an interview with Company A and Company B. Company A is my first choice (better work, better salary, better working conditions), but Company B is quite okay (i.e., I did not sell myself short).
Company B gave me a job-offer more or less directly after the interview, while Company A wanted to have a second interview which they could not schedule so soon, but they were informed about the job offer from Company B.
Since I wanted to have security, I accepted the contract from Company B, but also accepted the second interview with Company A.

**The Problem**

I really want to work at Company A and I am willing to resign from my contract with Company B. However, there are some legal restrictions when I can resign from my contract with Company B, hence the date where I can start with Company A (if they hire me) is moved a few weeks into the future.

In the forthcoming interview with Company A, I have to tell the first date I can start with them. **How can I communicate my situation without lying, but also keeping my chances high** (e.g., they should not think that I will do the same to them. They were my first choice from the very beginning)? When should I tell this in the interview? At the very beginning, or only when they ask me?

Comment: Which country/state is this? What happens if you don't turn up for work at company B on the proposed joining date? What you should do might depend on the answers to these questions.

Comment: Is there a question about how to manage two job applications concurrently? Because if there is we need to start putting it on billboards. For clarification accepted = signed? Country? Industry?

Comment: The country is Germany in the automobile industry. Accepted = signed. If I don't turn up for work, there will be a compensation of about a mountly salary. So I am planning to turn up there, at least to quit to job (and then work for 2 weeks, or they will probably discharge me. In both cases, I am legally not allowed to take another job in this time).

Comment: @NathanCooper It is more a question about how to tell Company A in a diplomatic way that I alreay signed for another job, but I am willing to resign from there (and will not do the same to Company A).

Comment: @job-offer-asker I don't know what the work culture in Germany is, but here in India, it would be considered pretty bad to resign on Day 1 (which, from your above comment, is what I interpret you are planning to do). It is preferred to inform the company well in advance that you won't be turning up, so they can at least save the hassles (and costs) of your joining formalities.

Comment: @Happy I agree with you that this point. But this is an other question how to deal with the resignation in Company B. I think, it is the best to inform them as soon as I get a contract signed with Company A.

Comment: Keep in mind: This will most likely burn all your bridges with company B. Also dont add this to your resume... The fewer people that know about this the better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're over-thinking this.  It's quite common to have a notice period from a previous job.

If the new company offers you the job, you tell them that your earliest available start date is XXth of Whenever.

You don't need to bring it up in the interview unless they specifically ask.  There's no point in giving them a reason not to hire you.