# I have been interviewing for my dream job, then things went fast with a different company and I receive an offer, how to professionally manage this?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, communication, job-offer, deadlines

I have been interviewing for the past two months with a company X that is one of "The big 4", for a dream job. Successfully finished several interviewing rounds and now my last and most difficult round is scheduled for 3 weeks from now.

I was reached out by Company Y which is mature (+600 employees) recently and done 2 rounds that went really fast, and quickly I receive an offer from them. Things went fast and truly I was not asked if I am interviewing outside, all what I was asked was when is your availability time to start and I said a month after submitting a notice.

I would want Company X, and today I asked them if we can move the last round to an earlier time (end of next week), they said they will be more than happy to do so and will get back to me before the end of today.

I know that I have a lot to prepare for my last round with Company X, but I don't want to decline the offer from Company Y (or maybe I would?). And I know that accepting (signing) with Company Y then changing my mind is unprofessional and would burn bridges, I guess.

How can I "push" Company Y to two or three or a month from now? Basically, enough time to prepare for round 3 with Company X, do it and then hear back from them for whether I will be hired or not. Is it ok to mention the entire plan to Company Y? I don't want to sound like "Oups sorry I forgot to say that I am interviewing with a different company".

Comment: Variations of this question have been asked many times on here, you might benefit from doing some searching. Generally though, there isn't a good single "correct" answer. You can always ask Company X to move things out, but they may decline.

Comment: Some similar questions: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/130562/should-i-tell-my-dream-job-i-rescinded-another-offer-to-wait-for-their-process?rq=1 https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41275/job-offer-accepted-having-another-interview-where-i-really-want-to-work-how-to?rq=1 https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/79327/a-company-wants-me-to-wait-for-the-other-companys-offer-to-then-make-a-decision?rq=1 https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/68179/is-it-reasonable-to-ask-for-a-week-to-consider-a-job-offer?rq=1

Comment: @dwizum I know and I went through similar Qs, there is still no clear approach for me, as you mentioned no single correct answer..

Comment: Also, keep in mind that while you are employing stalling tactics the company can at any point decide to just hire someone else.

Comment: @LambaDawet I think the fact that you're agreeing that there isn't a good single correct answer makes this somewhat un-answerable, no? It's hard for us to decide what you should do, you really need to consider the options and choose yourself.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to answer the question

> How can I "push" Company Y to two or three or a month from now?

For example, we don't know what kind of time frames you discussed with Company Y for the hiring process, or the time frame they had in mind for the beginning of employment with this role, whether it's a new role or you'd be replacing someone, etc etc. It also doesn't make sense to me that you said Company X would be happy to move the last round to a week from now but you think you need 2-3 months more time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always ask for delays, but a month's worth of delay can be problematic. When I was a hiring manager, I'd be unlikely to hold a position open that long - I'd likely move on to the next candidate before then.

It basically comes down to how much confidence you have in yourself and your abilities.

If you are not confident, take whatever job offer you have and don't look back. You have landed a really good job so there's little to be gained in risking it for a slightly better job possibility.

If you are confident, go for the job you really want. If that falls through you'll find another.

[Edit based on OP's comment]

> Hey Joe and thanks for your answer, Company X's compensation would be 200% for that of Company Y (and Y is 20% above my current salary).

Once again, if you are confident in yourself, go full bore for Company X at the expense of Company Y if necessary. Delay Company Y as long as you can get away with. If it comes down to it, just reject Company Y. There is always a Company Z if you are good enough.

Comment: Hey Joe and thanks for your answer, Company X's compensation would be 200% for that of Company Y (and Y is 20% above my current salary). What do you recommend in this case? I can't accept Company Y and never look back, that is a lot of money..

Comment: @LambaDawet That salary discrepancy should be part of the original question. For a 200% difference in salary, I bet more folks would be willing to risk burning a bridge here or there.

Answer (score 1):

Most companies don't assume you are only interviewing with them.  That said, your letting your dream cloud your judgement to the point of taking the wrong approach.  You should be using your offer letter as leverage to get big company to speed up their process.

If big company can't speed up their process, you're just a number to them.  If they can, they really want you.  Without them making an offer before the deadline, your question is reduced to "Should I accept an offer in hand, or remain unemployed with good prospects?"

Odds are the answer to that question will only depend on you, and what you can afford to choose.  Most people would see interviewing as a means to obtain a job, and now you have a job offer.  Note that "good prospects" is also highly subjective, odds are you have an incomplete visibility into the future.

If you are really confident, you can reject the offer and go for your dream job.  However, dreams and reality often are different.  You need to reflect on how aligned your dream job is with what is likely to be offered.  Remember, you're not guaranteed a job at big company, but assuming you do get the job at big company, there's no guarantee that big company's job is better, or even better for your career.

That said, I knew a person who was effectively underemployed for eight years as they attempted to get into the FBI.  They weren't paid highly in the FBI, but it was their lifelong dream, and they're very happy they made it in.

Whatever you decide, make that your dream job.  The passion you put in there will probably do more for your career than the name on the side of the building.